# Publish WCF service and web app in same target location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution that includes two projects: one regular `asp.net Web Application` developed in asp.net 4.0 and another project, a `WCF Service Application`.

They're both under the same solution, but both are deployed in different folders since I don't know how to deploy in the same project. The `WCF service` is used for reports from the asp.net website, so there's no reason they should be published in different target locations.

My question: is it possible to publish these two projects to the same target location? Or somehow join these two projects into one project that's deployed to the same target folder?

Comment: Are you asking about hosting them both in IIS?

Comment: They're already hosted in IIS, but each project is deployed in a different folder.

Comment: In VS, If I change the target folder so they're both the same, one will override the other.

Answer (score 0):

They cant just be deployed as a single application. A WCF service is designed to be able to be accessed by multiple applications not necessarily in the same project. You could have done this using Entity Framework or another method if they didnt really need to be seperated.